# C++ dot product to get if one object is in front of another?

Tags: c++

Im trying to use `Vector2::Dot` and `Math::Acos` to determine whether one gameobject is in front of another. With what I have, I'm able to get whether the first object's forward vector is at a perpendicular angle to second actor's forward vector:

```
float dotResult = Vector2::Dot(GetForwardDir(), secondActor->GetForward());
float angle = Math::Acos(dotResult);
    
if(angle <= minAngle)
    //do something
```

Where `GetForwardDir()` is:

```
return Vector2(Math::Cos(mRotation), -Math::Sin(mRotation));
```

However this does not account for where the second actor is relative to the first actor. I don't think Im understanding something here about `dotResult` and the `Acos` angle.

How can I use this to get whether the first actor is in front of the second?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a cross product for this. The dot product will give you a scaled `cos` for the angle between two vectors. A cross product will give you the `sin`, which is more useful here.

Basically, make two vectors:

- ActorA position + ActorA.Forward vector
- ActorA position + (ActorB.position - ActorA.position)

Or, just

- ActorA.forward X normalize(ActorB.Position - ActorA.position);

Since you're doing this in 2D, the result will be a scalar. If the sign of the result is positive, then ActorB is within 180º  (+- 90º) of ActorA's forward vector, from ActorA's position.

Technically, you're calculating an orthogonal vector, the Z component of which will tell you if the target is in front of or behind the viewer, but the X and Y components of that vector are zero, because orthogonal.

Purists will say that the cross product does not exist in 2D, and they're technically correct, but this is how it's done.